# How can I check if a computer is configured to use WSUS?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, wsus

I'm the user of a computer (Windows 7) that is part of a domain and I want to make sure its configured to use WSUS (Windows Server Update Services) and download updates from a local server instead of downloading updates directly from Microsoft servers.

Is there a way to definitely assert if WSUS is configured and maybe even obtain information about the configured WSUS server if one exists?

*Sidenote: I have no interest in setting up a WSUS server so I believe this question fits better in superuser than serverfault.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it is part of a domain, it is most likely done through group policy, you can go to the desktop as an administrator and open up the `Group Policy Editor` (Go to Run and type `MMC`, then go to `File` > `Add / Remove Snapin`) and find `Group Policy`.

Take a look under `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `Windows Update`.

If you are not using group policy, just take a look directly at the registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`

You should see the keys `WUServer` and `WUStatusServer` which should have the the locations of the specific servers.

There are far too many keys and entries for me to write, but if you are interested, Technet have an [excellent article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(WS.10).aspx) on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

All I ever do is open up Windows Updates from control panel.  If the machine is being managed by WSUS it will say "You receive updates:"  "Managed by your system administrator"

Comment: Think this just indicates there is GPO settings that are applied, not what they are (local source, from the internet, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Run `MMC`, `ADD/REMOVE SNap-in`, choose `Resultant Set of Policies`

... run it, you will see all applied GPOs, including WSUS settings

Comment: Doesn't this just duplicate the accepted answer from several years ago?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I wonder if this answer will give just domain GPO applied settings, whereas the other answer will also show locally set (not configured by domain GPO) settings.